# automatically scroll to bottom when new message is received or user sends new message jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello everyone I am developing real time chat it is working fine but when sometimes like in 2 - 5 seconds user sends 3 - 4 messages at once the scroller does no go to the bottom and I am not sure what exactly is happening here is my code

`

```
`    $(document).on('keypress', 'textarea[name=message]', function(e) {
       if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var myform = $('.sendMessage')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(myform);

        $.ajax({
            url  : $('.sendMessage').attr('action'),
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( response ) {
                var scrollPosition = false;

                if (($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight - $('#chat').scrollTop()).toFixed() == $('#chat').outerHeight()) {
                    scrollPosition = true;
                } 

                $('#chat').append(response.message);

                if(scrollPosition == true) {
                    $('#chat')[0].scrollTop = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight;
                    $('.jump-bottom').fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $('.jump-bottom').fadeIn();
                }

                $('input[name=chatCount]').val(response.chatCount);

                activatePopup();
                
                $('.post-project-comment').html('');
                $('#basic_message').html('');
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {
                $('#login-load').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $(this).val('');
       }
     });

    function updateChat(chatID, chatCount) {
    var chatUrlSet = $('input[name=chatMainUrl]').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    
    $.ajax({
        url      : chatUrlSet + '/' + chatID + '/' + chatCount,
        type     : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function( response ) {
            if(response.status == 1) {
                var scrollPosition = false;

                if (($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight - $('#chat').scrollTop()).toFixed() == $('#chat').outerHeight()) {
                    scrollPosition = true;
                } 

                $('#chat').append(response.message);

                if(scrollPosition == true) {
                    $('#chat')[0].scrollTop = $('#chat')[0].scrollHeight;
                    $('.jump-bottom').fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $('.jump-bottom').fadeIn();
                }

                $('input[name=chatCount]').val(response.chatCount);

                activatePopup();
            }               
        },
        error : function(request, status, error) {
            $('#login-load').fadeOut();
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    });
   }

    if($('.individual-match-chat').length > 0) {    
    setInterval(function() {
        var chatID    = $('input[name=thread]').val();
        var chatCount = $('input[name=chatCount]').val();

        if(chatID > 0) {
            updateChat(chatID, chatCount);
        }
    }, 1000);
    }`
```

above is my code so the issue is some times it does not automatically scrolls to the bottom I am really depressed why exactly is this happening or am I doing anything wrong is there anyone who can help me out

I created a function to update the chat after every 1 second in order to get updated messages received from the user but the code have glitches

Comment: It probably has something to do with duplicate callbacks. You are using an interval, but you are never sure your request success callback is finished before you are running the next iteration. You might want to cancel the iteration while another request is still being executed, remove the UI interaction from your success and move it to some other DOM-listener or use a css trick `overflow-anchor` instead. https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/pin-scrolling-to-bottom/

Comment: but what is user is scrolling top and then it should show button just like my code above and in whatsapp when new message is arrived user get notified jump to see new mesages